# Entanglement transfer of spin-entangled triplet-pair states between flying qubits and stationary qubits

Tags: architecture, entanglement, quantum-memory, solid-state

**The context**: We are in the solid state. After a photon absortion by a system with a singlet ground state, the system undergoes the spin-conserving fission of one spin singlet exciton into two spin triplet excitons (for context, see [The entangled triplet pair state in acene and heteroacene materials](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15953)). These spin triplet pair propagates in the solid, still entangled. The quantum-computing-related goal of all this operation would be to transfer the entanglement of the two flying qubits to two positions that are fixed in space and are also well protected from decoherence (low-energy excitations of nuclear spins in a paramagnetic ion, for example).

**The problem at hand** (1), and the question: What would be the requirements to favour said quantum information transfer between the flying qubits and the stationary qubits?
(I know flying vs stationary qubit scenarios have been explored, but I have no experience in that field).

Comment: are you asking in general how the information in "flying qubits" can be transferred into "stationary qubits"? What do you mean by "flying qubits", photons?

Comment: here "flying qubits" are electronic spin triplet states propagating through space in the solid state matrix; I'm asking, (if possible) in particular or (if not) in general, for the conditions to favour coherent transfer between those (comparatively) high-energy excitations and the low-energy states of either electronic spin states, or, preferredly, nuclear spin states; if it works like pulsed EPR or pulsed NMR, I guess a resonant optical pulse with the right selection rules could do that, but I look for a more authoritative answer; I'd be happy to edit the answer or accept edits to clarify